# Doctrine/Symfony generated migrations out of order

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but it sure seems like one to me.

When I generate migrations using generate-migrations-diff involving tables that have foreign keys in Symfony, the migrations that result seem to be out of order.

For instance, assuming I have a foreign key in table A to table B, and I delete table B and the referencing field in Table A, the first migration drops Table B and the column in Table A whereas the second migration then drops the foreign key constraint in Table A.  The first migration does not work as the field in Table A with the foreign key constraint cannot be dropped, nor can Table B be dropped because of the foreign key constraint.

What should happen is that the foreign key constraint should be dropped first, and *then* the table and fields should be dropped.

I'm using mysql 5.1.37 as my DBMS.

Here's some of the generated code:

```
class Version94 extends Doctrine_Migration_Base
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->dropTable('B');
        $this->removeColumn('A', 'b_id');
    }
.
.
.


class Version95 extends Doctrine_Migration_Base
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->dropForeignKey('A', 'a_b_id_b_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly a bug. In my experience, `doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` is very unreliable and will generate incorrect migrations for more complex changes.

You can report the issue [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa).